# Changing Access modifier using reflection in kotlin

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I know in java if I wish to use reflection to set a final field I can change the access modifier of the field like so:

```
Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("someField");
field.setAccessible(true);

Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
```

I am have difficulty achieving the same thing in kotlin. The problem is with the bitwise operators on the final line `modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL)`. Admittedly I am somewhat ignorant of bitwise operators in general and do not know the kotlin equivalents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Immediately after posting the question I found the solution. The bitwise operators that are being used and their java representations are **AND** (`$`) and **bitwise compliment** (`~`).

In kotlin the **AND** bitwise operator is an infix function of the `Int` class [and](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/and.html). Similarly the **bitwise compliment** operator is also a function, [inv](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/inv.html), on the `Int` class.

The way to change the modifier in kotlin is:

```
val field = clazz.getDeclaredField("someField")
field.isAccessible = true

val modifers = field.javaClass.getDeclaredField("modifiers")
modifers.isAccessible = true
modifers.setInt(field, field.modifiers and Modifier.FINAL.inv())
```